# Stringizing macro arguments in a multi-level macro call

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros, stringification

I have a macro like this:

```
#define SHOW_EXPR(x) printf ("%s=%d\n", #x, (x))
```

It works:

```
#define FOO 123
int BAR = 456;
SHOW_EXPR(FOO+BAR);
```

This prints `FOO+BAR=579` as expected.

Now I'm trying to define a macro that calls SHOW_EXPR:

```
#define MY_SHOW_EXPR(x) (printf ("Look ma, "), SHOW_EXPR(x))
MY_SHOW_EXPR(FOO+BAR)
```

This prints `Look ma, 123+BAR=579`, which is also expected, but this is not what I want.

Is it possible to define MY_SHOW_EXPR such that it does the right thing?

(Actual macros are a bit more complicated than shown here. I know that macros are evil.)

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Something like `Look ma, FOO+BAR=579` would be nice ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macros are like kitchen knifes, you can do evil things with them but they are not evil as such.

I'd do something like this

```
#define SHOW_EXPR_(STR, EXP) printf (STR "=%d\n", EXP)
#define SHOW_EXPR(...) SHOW_EXPR_(#__VA_ARGS__, (__VA_ARGS__))
#define MY_SHOW_EXPR(...) SHOW_EXPR_("Look ma, " #__VA_ARGS__, (__VA_ARGS__))
```

which as an extra feature even would work if the expression contains a comma.

Comment: Thanks. Changing the original macro is not desirable but if nothing else helps...

Comment: @Jens: Perhaps `__VA_ARGS__` rather than `__VA_ARG__`?

Comment: @JosephQuinsey, most probably. This is the result of usually having autocompletion, so I never have to remember the exact spelling of such random names. I'll edit that.